# How to use aggregate and summary function to get unique columns in a dataframe?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have used the aggregate function to get a summary of results based on their collection location. The summary returns 3 obs. of 2 variables. One variable is the group name, one is the summary statistic per group.

How do I get R to view each column (Group, min, 1st quartile, median, etc.) as unique in my data frame? Ultimately I'd like this to be 3 obs. of 7 variables, one for each column. OR I'd like to know how to cleanly get min, median, and max by Location. Thanks!

```
Result <- c(1,1,2,100,50,30,45,20, 10, 8)
Location <- c("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Alpha")

df <- data.frame(Result, Location)
head(df)

Agg <- aggregate(df$Result, list(df$Location), summary)

head(Agg)
   Group.1 x.Min. x.1st Qu. x.Median x.Mean x.3rd Qu. x.Max.
1   Alpha   1.00      6.25    26.50  38.50     58.75 100.00
2    Beta   1.00     10.50    20.00  23.67     35.00  50.00
3   Gamma   2.00      6.00    10.00  14.00     20.00  30.00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `aggregate`'s `simplify` parameter defaults to `TRUE`, it's simplifying the results of calling the function (here, `summary`) to a matrix. You can reconstruct the data.frame, coercing the column into its own data.frame:

```r
df <- data.frame(Result = c(1,1,2,100,50,30,45,20, 10, 8),
                 Location = c("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Alpha"))

Agg <- aggregate(df$Result, list(df$Location), summary)

data.frame(Location = Agg$Group.1, Agg$x)
#>   Location Min. X1st.Qu. Median     Mean X3rd.Qu. Max.
#> 1    Alpha    1     6.25   26.5 38.50000    58.75  100
#> 2     Beta    1    10.50   20.0 23.66667    35.00   50
#> 3    Gamma    2     6.00   10.0 14.00000    20.00   30
```

Alternately, dplyr's `summarise` family of functions can handle multiple summary statistics well:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Location) %>% summarise_all(funs(min, median, max))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Location   min median   max
#>   <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Alpha       1.   26.5  100.
#> 2 Beta        1.   20.0   50.
#> 3 Gamma       2.   10.0   30.
```

If you really want all of `summary`, you can use `broom::tidy` to turn each group's results into a data frame in a list column, which can be `unnest`ed:

```r
df %>% 
    group_by(Location) %>% 
    summarise(x = list(broom::tidy(summary(Result)))) %>% 
    tidyr::unnest()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#>   Location minimum    q1 median  mean    q3 maximum
#>   <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 Alpha         1.  6.25   26.5  38.5  58.8    100.
#> 2 Beta          1. 10.5    20.0  23.7  35.0     50.
#> 3 Gamma         2.  6.00   10.0  14.0  20.0     30.
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed summary, @alistaire. Both of these work! I definitely prefer the dplyr option because it works easily with multiple parameters all in one data frame (would have to hack  the `aggregate` more to make that happen, and it would be much less pretty to do so).

Comment: One additional question, @alistaire... Do you know if you can perform log means and log standard deviations with dplyr `summarise` functions?

Comment: You can use anything you can type which returns a single value. If you're doing more than just using a pre-formed function, you'll need to replace the variable with `.` in `funs`, e.g. `summarise_all(funs(log_mean = log(mean(.)), log_sd = log(sd(.))))`

Comment: hmmm okay. Logarithmic mean may be a bit more complicated for this function. Log mean is equal to the difference of the numbers divided by the logarithm of their quotient. I'll keep researching... thanks!

Comment: That's only possible for two numbers at a time. You could chuck it into `Reduce`, but I'm not sure that's what you want.